# How can I destroy a material of a gameobject and add a new material to it using editor script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
var newmat = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath("Assets/Materials/Univeral Render Pipeline Lit.mat", typeof(Material));

        var allgameobjects = FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>();

        foreach(GameObject go in allgameobjects)
        {
            if (go.GetComponent<Renderer>() != null)
            {
                if (go.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial.name.StartsWith("Default"))
                {
                    DestroyImmediate(go.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial);

                    // Add here the newmat material to the gameobject
                }
            }
        }
```

This will destroy remove the current material from a gameobject how can I add a new material to it ? I want to add the newmat to it.

Maybe there is no need to destroy just to switch the materials ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var newmat = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath("Assets/Materials/Univeral Render Pipeline Lit.mat", typeof(Material));

        var allgameobjects = FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>();

        foreach(GameObject go in allgameobjects)
        {
            if (go.GetComponent<Renderer>() != null)
            {
                if (go.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial.name.StartsWith("Default"))
                {
                    DestroyImmediate(go.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial);

                    //Add material
                    go.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial = newmat;
                }
            }
        }
```

But I think you could just change the material too

```
var newmat = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath("Assets/Materials/Univeral Render Pipeline Lit.mat", typeof(Material));

        var allgameobjects = FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>();

        foreach(GameObject go in allgameobjects)
        {
            if (go.GetComponent<Renderer>() != null)
            {
                if (go.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial.name.StartsWith("Default"))
                {
                    go.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial = newmat;
                }
            }
        }
```

for terrain, it is `terrain.materialTemplate`

Comment: It's working both ways but for some reason it didn't work on the Terrain. There is a small button near the terrain material name Create to create a new material maybe somehow I need to use it ?

Comment: I think for terrain it is ``terrain.materialTemplate``